# Cannot view the logfile?

Tags: filesystem, permissions, system

I am a beginner. I have managed to install Ubuntu 11.10 and am now satisfied that it seems to be running okay. It would help me learn more to be able to view the logfile but I cannot. What have I missed or what am I dping wrong (also I have no swap file just incase this maybe related). Any help appreciated please.

Answer (score 1):

The system logs are restricted to `root` for security reasons.  Learn to use `sudo`.  (Or for a singleuser system where you're reasonably confident about security, you can change the permissions on the log files yourself.)